# How can I monitor a Python process and relaunch if it dies?

Tags: python, linux

I have a program that I'm running that listens to a queue (it's not multi-threaded so I want to run several instances of it).  I've tried my best to catch errors but in the event the app crashes due to a error or bad incoming data, I want to be able to respawn the Python app (after I log the stacktrace) so it continues to work.

I felt this might be a common problem for people who run python based services so I thought I would ask but I was thinking of writing some code to do a `ps -ef` and count the instances of the name of the Python program (if less than a threshold then I would have the program relaunch it).

Before I build this, I wanted to know if there was perhaps a better way or a existing tool/module that did this?

Comment: try googling for "watchdog" that's what this kind of task is often called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).  I use it regularly to launch, monitor all types of things.

Here is how I set it up to launch a wsgi app on my server:

```
[program:quizzes]
directory = /var/www/quizzes.seasources.net
command = /home/jaime/code/virtualenv/quizzes/bin/uwsgi uwsgi.ini
process_name = quizzes
autostart = true
startsecs = 5
user = www-data
redirect_stderr = true
stdout_logfile = /var/www/quizzes.seasources.net/logs/supervisor-console.log
environment = PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=/tmp/python-eggs
```

The configuration file format is easy to understand and it even logs stdout/stderr to a file.  Above it's /var/www/quizzes.seasources.net/logs/supervisor-console.log  You can read more about configuration [here](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point, I included a simple configuration section that I use myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a supervisor. A well known one that's written in Python would be [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), a more recent one also in Python would be [Circus](https://circus.readthedocs.org/), and then there are Monit or daemontools and probably many more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something more simple, you can use the subprocess module (python default) to start and check your processes...
A basic version would look like this:

```
# run.py

import subprocess, time

# add your listener processor call here
_PROCESS_ARGS = ['python','/path/to/listener.py']
_PROCESS_TOTAL = 10

process_list = []

# start the processes...
for i in range(_PROCESS_TOTAL):     
    process_list.append(subprocess.Popen(_PROCESS_ARGS))

while True:     
    for i in range(_PROCESS_TOTAL):         
        p = process_list[i]         
            if p.poll() != None: # check if process is running                      
                process_list[i] = subprocess.Popen(_PROCESS_ARGS) # if not, replace with new one
    time.sleep(1) # check only every second...
```